# Segmentation fault using pthreads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I am writing a program to test my understanding of condition variables. Basically, thread 0 checks if count is even, and if so, increments it. If not, then it signals thread 1 which increments the count variable. The process continues until count reaches 15. Here is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define numThreads 2

int count=0;
pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;
pthread_cond_t count_threshold_cv;


void *checkEven(void *threadId)
{   while(count<=15){
//lock the mutex
pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
printf("even_thread: thread_id=%d  count=%d\n",threadId,count); 
if(count%2==0){
count++;
}
else{
printf("Odd count found, signalling to odd thread\n");
pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
sleep(1);
}
}

void *checkOdd(void *threadId)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);   //obtain a lock
while(count<=15){
pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &count_mutex);   //wait() relinquishes the lock 
count++;
printf("odd_thread: thread_id=%d, count=%d\n",threadId,count);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{ 
pthread_t threads[numThreads];
int rc;
int a=0;
int b=0;
pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, checkEven, (void *)a);
pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, checkEven, (void *)b);
pthread_join(0,NULL);
pthread_join(1,NULL);
pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting segmentation fault(core dumped) error with this? I know that this error occurs when one process tries to violate the address space of some other process, but nothing beyond this.Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: The thing is that the even thread calls signal as soon as count is odd. Thus, the odd thread gets the lock and continues after the wait() call, and increments count. It then unlocks and the even thread gets the lock, and the cycle continues.

Comment: You don't initialize your `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t` properly.

Comment: I think that is not the reason for the problem it was facing. Actually, I had messed-up the calls to join(), by passing 0 instead of threads[0].

Comment: I never said it was the reason for the behavior you observe. I'm just pointing out that your code is incorrect in this regard.

Comment: Thanks @EOF. Can you tell me what is wrong with it? I have been initializing them like this, even since I started. When am I wrong?

Comment: @PrashantPandey It's always been wrong and it always will be wrong. This just happens to work on Linux. There are two legal ways to initialize a mutex or condition variable, and you aren't doing either of them.

Comment: Objects with static storage duration are initialized to zero or null of the appropriate type. Some `pthread` implementations take care to design their `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t` in such a way that zero-initialization produces well-initialized mutexes/condvars, but this is not guaranteed by the standard. You need to use the proper initializers.

Comment: Got it man. One hell of a buggy code I think.

Comment: Please indent youc code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a zero to `pthread_join` as the thread you want to join:

```
pthread_join(0,NULL);
```

You wanted:

```
pthread_join(threads[0],NULL);
pthread_join(threads[1],NULL);
```

You have several other bugs though. For one thing, your `checkOdd` code calls `pthread_cond_wait` even when it's that thread's turn.

You don't seem to understand condition variables. Specifically, you seem to think that somehow the condition variable will know whether or not the thing you are waiting for has happened. It does not -- condition variables are stateless. It's your job to keep track of what you're waiting for and whether or not it has happened.

Comment: But doesn't it continue after wait() when signaled by the even thread?

Comment: @PrashantPandey Yes, but the even thread will only signal it if it's the even thread's turn. If you wait even when it's *already* your turn, you'll be waiting forever.

Comment: The condition variable has no idea which thread's turn it is. If you call `pthread_cond_wait`, it will wait, whether or not it should wait. So don't call `pthread_cond_wait` unless you are 100% sure you want to wait, which you can only be if it's not your turn. But you don't check.

Comment: Okay. So, you're suggesting that I  first check for a condition, and if not true, then call wait(), are you not?

Comment: The standard pattern is: `while (this_thread_needs_to_wait) pthread_cond_wait(...);`. How you check whether or not the thread needs to wait is up to you. You do need the `while` loop because `pthread_cond_wait` cannot guarantee it only returns when it's your turn because it has no idea when it is or isn't your turn. Condition variables are stateless.

Comment: Thanks @David Schwartz. I am making changes.